# Where is println and other global symbols documented in groovy and where are they defined?

Tags: groovy

I have been using Groovy for a while but like everyone, I took the println function without much afterthought or real explanation at the beginning (same for printf, etc.). However, I could not find a place in the official Groovy documentation where all those 'global' symbols are defined, etc. Or maybe they are just syntax sugar that end up being compiled into actual existing classes and method calls? Any clue on that guys?

Comment: It's defined here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#println(java.lang.Object)

Comment: So it's added to the object metaclass, so exists everywhere

Comment: in groovy Script [print*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#print(java.lang.Object)) functions redefined to print into `out` variable. so, `out = new PrintStream(new File('out.txt'))` could redefine `print*` behavior for scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is println and other global symbols documented in groovy and
> where are they defined?

`println` in particular, as well as a bunch of other dynamic methods that groovy adds to existing classes, is documented at http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/.  If you look at `java.lang.Object` there you will see the `println` method documented.  That `println` is defined at https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/9375459763f0d664d0acbc9ce120a03b5a1da4ad/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L759.